# Upload video using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello im trying to upload a video to my folder and ive searched questions already with answers and tried them all and it seems none of them are working.
i want both image and video uploaded in the same input

here is my code in my view

```
$('#upload_image_button').on('click', function(){
          var imageFile = $('input[name=upload_image_input]');
          var imageToUpload = imageFile[0].files[0];
          var imageName = $('#upload_image_name').val();
          $('#Upload_Image').val(imageName);


           if(imageToUpload) {

                      //Provide the form data that would be sent to server through ajax
                      var formData = new FormData();
                      var uploadURI = '<?php echo base_url('uploadImage'); ?>';

                     formData.append('upload_image_input', imageToUpload);

                      //Upload the file using ajax
                      $.ajax({
                          type: 'POST'
                          , url: uploadURI
                          , data: formData
                          , processData: false
                          , contentType: false
                          , success: function() {
                            var image = '<?php echo base_url("assets/images/'+ imageName +'"); ?>';
                              //$('#profile_pic').attr('src', image);
                              Materialize.toast('Image Attached', 4000);
                          }
                          , error: function(errorw){
                              Materialize.toast('Something went wrong. Please try again', 4000);
                          }
                      });
                  }
                  else{
                      Materialize.toast('Field Empty', 4000);
                  }

    });
```

and here is my code for my controller

```
public function uploadImage(){
    $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/files';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4|3gp|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['max_size']     =0;
    $config['max_width']    =0;
    $config['max_height']   =0;

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('upload_image_input')) {
            //File upload
            $uploadData = $this->upload->data(); 
            $filename = $uploadData['file_name'];
         // $this->loginmodel->upload_model($filename,$account_id);
        }   
}
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: no errors in the console im at lost

Comment: Add a else statement in your php code to print upload error using echo $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>'); and then check console for response

Comment: thank you i found out the problem it says file size exceeds upload data i changed my upload max from 20 to 8 and it worked